# Statistical Significance of two unequal sets

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

If we have two groups with the probability of some action and in 1 group-prob equals to 30% and in the 2 group-35% can we say that prob is significantly higher in 2 group if there are 1000 observation in 1 group and 20 observation in the 2 group?

I guess, the answer is no. But can you please help me with the explanation? Should we have equal sets and compare them using for example t-test or they can differ from each other?

Comment: It is fine to have unequal sizes, but t-test seems unlikely to work here. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "probability", you mean "observed proportion". In that case, you have a 2 × 2 contingency table, where one dimension of the table is the subject's group and the other is whether or not the subject performed the action, and you want to test the null hypothesis that these variables are independent. One test for this is Fisher's exact test.

A $t$-test is inappropriate because you have two independent variables, not just one, and the dependent variable is a count.